# Xamarin CarouselView and the List -> Detail paradigm

Tags: listview, xamarin, carousel, detailview

Wanted to pick your brains on how to display and navigate from a List view to the Detailview when using the CarouselView navigation paradigm.

Specifically, suppose you have a Carousel page such as this:

```
<ContentPage>
    <Grid>
       <CarouselView>
           <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
               <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                  <c:View0 />
                  <c:View1 />
                  <c:View2 />
           </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
       </CarouselView>
   </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Suppose also that one of the views (say, View1) in the Carousel contains a list of products fetched from your database, eg:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding listofproducts}" SelectionChanged="OnItemClicked">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackLayout>
                 <Label Text="{Binding productname}"
             </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

How would you go about showing the product's details page when the user triggers OnItemClicked()?  If you open a detailed view, wouldn't that confuse the CarouselView navigation logic? And how would you get to the list page?

Not sure what kind of an approach would work here.
Any ideas/examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure how you think the Carousel would be "confused"?  Just do a PushAsync - I don't see why that wouldn't work.  Although having a list in a Carousel seems like bad UX to me - I would worry more about confusing the user.

Comment: That's what I meant, confusing the user, not the control itself.  The thing is, I really like the Carousel paradigm, and I'd like to make it work with the List -> Detail paradigm, but I am not sure how to make these two concepts gel.

Comment: I would just try it out and see what the behavior is like for the user

Comment: I did and it's confusing.  Once the user is on the Details page, it's not obvious where (s)he could go from there.   What surprises me is that this appears to me quite a common usage scenario for using Carousel navigation, but I've yet to find any examples or attempts at it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your needs I wrote a small example for your reference.

First create a CarouselView on the xaml page, add a CollectionView inside it and add a click event.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Mydates}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   BorderColor="DarkGray"
                   CornerRadius="5"
                   Margin="20"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding data2}">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers >
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

The click information can be obtained in the background method, and then you can make other logical judgments.

Here is the background code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
     
    public ObservableCollection<Class1> Mydates { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Mydates.Add(new Class1() { data1 = "aaa",data2 = new List<string>() { "aaa","bbb","cccc"} });
        Mydates.Add(new Class1() { data1 = "bbb", data2 = new List<string>() { "ddd", "eeee", "ffffff" } });
        Mydates.Add(new Class1() { data1 = "ccc", data2 = new List<string>() { "ggg", "hhhh", "iii" } });
        BindingContext = this;
    }


    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sta = sender as StackLayout;
        var mydata = (sta.Children[0] as Label).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you.

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: Well, it wasn't so much of a problem, as an invitation to consider different approaches. Your approach is interesting, thank you.  Let's see if others have other ideas.